# Reading a matrix in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program in C that reads my matrix and calculates the sum of elements,
but it gives me an error at scanf("%d",&a[i]). This is the error :

```
      warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int 
    (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]
```

and this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    int m,n,a[10][10],s=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
 
 
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
            s=s+a[i][j];
    
    printf("%d",s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Please sort out the indentation an use braces

Comment: Don't forget array start from 0 in c.

Comment: @mpromonet why 0 to n-1 and not 1 to n?? i think its fine like this too

Comment: @JustAsking, it is not fine, it is using unallocated memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `scanf("%d",&a[i]);`
to `scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);`
as you need to give him the address to write on but you give the address of array of ten int

Comment: Might be handy to check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: oh shooot i;m so stupid, thank you!!! been staring at this for 10 minutes and didn't realise lol